# What are the various stats representing on OpenSea Retrieve collection stats request

Tags: opensea

I am working on something for a client, and I need to access the collection stats.  The problem is im a little confused about what some of these fields mean..

Esentially what confuses me is you have ... change | ...difference

Im trying to find ... and are the numbers in percentages. or eth or ... its just not documented at all and its really starting to stress me out because theres no way to deconstruct the values and try to see what they mean ... like one day change -18.000 no values are -18 percent from anything else on this page...

```
one_hour_volume: 12.0275,
one_hour_change: 1.1100877192982455,
one_hour_sales: 2,
one_hour_sales_change: 1,
one_hour_average_price: 6.01375,
one_hour_difference: 6.3275,
six_hour_volume: 17.7275,
six_hour_change: 0,
six_hour_sales: 3,
six_hour_sales_change: 0,
six_hour_average_price: 5.909166666666667,
six_hour_difference: 17.7275,
one_day_volume: 41.803630999999996,
one_day_change: -0.3037914920051229,
one_day_sales: 7,
one_day_sales_change: -0.2222222222222222,
one_day_average_price: 5.971947285714285,
one_day_difference: -18.241069000000003,
seven_day_volume: 363.33193099999994,
seven_day_change: 0.21475368195741737,
seven_day_sales: 55,
seven_day_average_price: 6.606035109090908,
seven_day_difference: 64.23266799999993,
thirty_day_volume: 1336.1454120000012,
thirty_day_change: -0.4431526340520433,
thirty_day_sales: 179,
thirty_day_average_price: 7.464499508379895,
thirty_day_difference: -1063.336912434444,

total_volume: 151308.38145222023,
total_sales: 24199,
total_supply: 10000,
count: 10000,
num_owners: 5459,
average_price: 6.252670831531065,
num_reports: 1,
market_cap: 66060.35109090908,
floor_price: 6.2699
```

Comment: Same here. What about `total_supply` vs `count`?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation should be improved. I added a feature request on the [opensea-js GitHub repository](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-js/issues/820). After some trial and error, I found that the `change` and `difference` suffixes both reference the same statistic:

> They both show the difference between the volume achieved in the current hour and the volume reached in the previous hour.

The only difference is that the `change` variable is expressed as a *decimal fraction* while the `difference` variable is
displayed in the collection's base currency. Unfortunately, I was also unable to figure out the difference between the `total_supply` and `count` JSON fields. There may be a difference for specific NFT standards, or they reserved this for future developments.